# Get the string or text automatically as column N = "OK" when column C = "Valid"

Tags: google-sheets

I am newbee, I am using googlespreadsheet and trying to add text or string in Column N when Column C = "Valid" then Column N = "OK" can anyone help please? I want to use custom formula for that.

I am new to this and looking forward any help appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try this in `Cell_N1` (screenshot should help):*

```js
=arrayformula(if(C:C="Valid","OK",))
```

[image]